# Wubi install on AMD64 - won't boot to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, wubi

Have successfully installed Ubuntu on 3 other machines 2 x 11.10 and 1 x 12.04LTS  but having problems with:

Dell Inspiron 1721 AMD Turion 64 2GHz with 2 GB ram, 320GB HD with 100GB free running Vista Home Premium.

Downloaded and installed 12.04LTS via Wubi, setting 20GB size to test machine.
All appears ok until the reboot.

Loads the Ubuntu splash screen then displays the following:

```
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:

    - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
      - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?
      - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
    - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/08A89A44A89E2FE4 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell
```

Any ideas as to why it won't boot to UBUNTU?

---

Managed to identify additional messages when trying to boot:

```
Try (hd0,0) FAT16 NO WUBILDR; 
Try (hd0,1) NTFS5 No wubildr; 
Try (hd0,2) NTFS5 error: "prefix" is not set
```

Does this help?

Comment: Managed to identify additional messages when trying to boot: 
Try (hd0,0) FAT16 NO WUBILDR; 
Try (hd0,1) NTFS5 No wubildr; 
Try (hd0,2) NTFS5 error: "prefix" is not set

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Turian64 won't run the PAE kernel.  There's a non PAE version of 12.04 out there.  Use it.

Comment: Do you a reference or sources for this information?

Comment: Indeed, a reference and more importantly, a link to the non pae kernel would make this answer far more helpful.

Comment: @david6 If the assertion is true I would expect to find numerous hits for it with Google. I haven't. But more to the point, the OP's problems seem to occur long before entering an Ubuntu kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same kind of problem, except I do not have any Windows installed on my pc. It used to run fine on Oneiric, so I don't think it's a hardware or bios settings problem.

It's definitely not a problem with wubi. As far as I can see, initramfs loads but it does not 'see' the root partition.

I've checked my /etc/fstab from the live cd (on usb) and all UUID's are correct. I installed boot-repair on the live usb and ran it after verifying all options. I did not set the boot flag on /dev/sda1 in boot-repair, going to try that now.

What I'm going to try if that does not work is uncommenting the line in /etc/default/grub about using UUID's.

I googled all day to find a solution, but found nothing really useful. This is as far as I got until now. Maybe this can be of some help to others.

http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?35174-kubuntu-fails-to-load-after-grub-menu
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9579872

Also found this, although I don't have a RAID-system (and disabled all raid in the BIOS):
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11859557
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/931929

As I said, Oneiric worked fine and an upgrade from Oneiric did not cause any problems either. It may be a solution to install Oneiric Ocelot first and then upgrade from there. Bit of an annoying workaround, but as long as it works...

Comment: Ok, tried all options except installing through an upgrade of a fresh Oneiric install. Seems like the only option left, all other stuff just doesn't work. Hopefully there will be a proper solution for this soon. On another system it worked just fine, I have no clue why.

Comment: Tried 11.10 wubi install same problem, but only got as far as the messages I put in the comment to my original post - Any ideas?